# Current mirror design using PMOS

Tags: mosfet, analog, cmos

I am designing a PMOS current mirror in 350nm Cadence technology [attached].
Problem: keeping the dimension (W/L ratio) of both the PMOS transistors constant, I should get mirrored current the same as the reference current (according to mirror circuit principle). But I am not getting the same current as reference current. e.g.

0. When my reference current is 10uA then the mirror current is 16.6uA with 5V supply voltage (Vdd)

When I change the supply voltage then the mirror current started getting better as e.g.

1. Reference current 10uA then the mirror current is 13.4uA with 3.3V supply voltage (Vdd).
2. Reference current 10uA then the mirror current is 10.3uA with 1.8V supply voltage (Vdd).

- Dimension of MPO: W/L=10u/0.5u
- Dimension of MP1: W/L=10u/0.5u

I would like to know How and Why my mirror current is changing with changing supply voltage (Vdd)?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output current will only be exactly the same as the input current when both transistors have **exactly** the same voltages across all terminals.

Their \$V_{GS}\$ are the same as the gates and sources are in parallel.

But what about the drain and \$V_{DS}\$?

Hint: learn about "[channel length modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_length_modulation)".

Short channel, L = 0.5 um: the channel length modulation will have a large influence

Long channel, L = 5 um: the channel length modulation will have a much smaller influence

To (almost) completely eliminate the influence of channel length modulation you will need a more complex circuit like a 3-transistor current mirror.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it.

Answer (score -1):

Following up on Bimpelrekkie answer, I see four choices

- Use longer channel devices
- Use cascading, where base(if bipolar) or gate(if fet) is held at some voltage below the Pch Sources, so the mirror device is in Saturation (stiff Iout) region; this may be needed to tolerate HIGH VOLTAGES; if you have wells for your Pch, this will allow operation up to the Well_Drain breakdown potential.
- Use a 3 transistor mirror
- Use lumped resistors in the Sources of your two Pch; when I initially worked in the discrete/PCB world and did not have access to thermally_tracking matched devices, I'd use resistors sized to provide 0.2 volts I * R drop; being much greater than 0.026 volts, the (bipolars) tracked well and were less affected by Early Effect.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your comments give me a new direction to think of.